# How do you identify a RAW or JPEG image within Lightroom 3?

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-3, raw-vs-jpeg

I usually shoot RAW photos.

Once in a while I will switch back to JPEG.

Is there a way to identify which photos are RAW in Lightroom library and such?

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do this:

- Hover over the image in the Library module and you'll see some information about the image, including the filename.
- In the right-hand sidebar of the Library module look in the Metadata section and find the File Name field.
- Use the Expanded grid view style in the Library module (View > Grid View Style > Expanded Cells). Control what is displayed in the cell (including file name or extension) by choosing View > Grid View Style> View Options. Similarly, in the Develop module you can use the Loupe Info Overlay and View options (in the View menu) to display this information.
- Or, filter photos: use the Filter bar to get just the photos you want, or create a Smart Collection to find them.

Answer (score 2):

Lightroom will show you the extension of the file, which should point you in the right direction, but if that's not quite good enough, try creating a Smart Collection -- you can filter by file type there, including RAW vs. JPG.

Answer (score 0):

(In windows) if you just hover over an item in Library view in Lightroom it will show you the filename and the extension of that file.

Answer (score 0):

I use four different ways. More probably exist, but this is what I find handy.

[image]

Note: this example has the sort option shown as well as the image filename of the selected image.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a Custom Text Filter on "Filename", "Ends With" and "jpg"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:

Open the photo in Loupe mode, press "*i*" and you will see the photo meta data information like the shutter speed, aperture, focal length, and the file's extension which will be either (in your case) jpeg or your camera raw extension.